# Error with escape characters

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want this hyperlink to call a javascript function so i need it to have an id and i want it to not redirect anywhere...just to trigger click event. (If it can be done and with a p element please let me know) .To achieve it  (hyperlink or p) i tried to use escape characters but it doesnt work. I get an error. What am i typing wrong?

```
player.bindPopup("<a id=&quot;show-profile&quot; href=&quot;#&quot;>"+data.inname[i]+"</a>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way it works

```
player.bindPopup("<a id='show-profile' href='#'>"+data.inname[i]+"</a>");
```